# How to handle PHP 7 Error exceptions using framework exception handling in ZF2?

Tags: php, events, error-handling, event-handling, zend-framework2

For (Zend Framework) exceptions I use a simple mechanism shown below:

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Log\Logger;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
        // ...
        $this->initExceptionHandler($e);
    }

    public function initExceptionHandler($event)
    {
        $sharedManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $sharedManager->attach(
            'Zend\Mvc\Application',
            [MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR], 
            function ($event) use($serviceManager) {
                // error log
                // ...
                // error page
                ...
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Now I want to implement the error handling for the native PHP errors. In PHP 7 "*most errors are now reported by throwing [Error](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) exceptions*" (s. [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php)). So they can be easily caught: either with a `try-catch` block or via the [`set_exception_handler(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

In order to avoid needless code duplication, I want to "convert" PHP error exceptions to exceptions catchable by the already implemented mechanism. The idea is to "wrap" errors in `MvcEvent`s and forward them to the (framework) exception error handling. What I've tried so far:

```
// ...
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        // ...
        $this->initExceptionHandler($e);
        $this->initErrorHandler($e);
    }
    // ...
    public function initErrorHandler($event)
    {
        set_exception_handler(function (\Throwable $exception) use ($event) {
            $event->getApplication()->getEventManager()->trigger(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, $event);
        });
    }
}
```

The result is only a white page and no error messages (so nothing on the page, nothing new in the custom error log, nothing new in the `syslog`).

**How to dock/connect the PHP native error handling to the (framework) exception handling, so that errors cause triggering of error events and can be processed as (framework) exceptions?**

---

**UPDATE**

The problem with the logging was, that the `$event#params['exception']` was not set, so the line `$serviceManager->get('ErrorLogger')->crit($event->getParam('exception'), $extra);` in the `Module#initExceptionHandler(...)` could not be executed. Now I'm setting this and some other parameters of the `$event` manually:

```
public function initErrorHandler(MvcEvent $event)
{
    set_exception_handler(function (\Throwable $exception) use ($event) {
        $event->setError(Application::ERROR_EXCEPTION);
        $routeMatch        = $event->getRouteMatch();
        $controllerName    = 'Application\Controller\Error';
        $event->setController($controllerName);
        $controllerManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('controller_manager'); // ->get('controllers');
        $controller = $controllerManager->get($controllerName);
        $event->setControllerClass(get_class($controller));
        $event->setParam('exception', $exception);
        $viewModel = new ViewModel();
        $viewModel->setCaptureTo('content');
        $viewModel->setTemplate('error/index');
        $viewModel->setTerminal(false);
        $viewModel->setVariables([
            'message' => 'An error occurred during execution; please try again later.',
            'display_exceptions' => true
        ]);
        $event->setResult($viewModel);
        // From this moment the framework exception handling starts and cares about the logging and displaying the error data.
        // $event->getApplication()->getEventManager()->trigger(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, $event);
        $event->setName(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR);
        $event->getApplication()->getEventManager()->triggerEvent($event);
        return false;
    });
}
```

This way I've got the logging working. But in the frontend I'm still getting an empty page. **What is wrong here and how to to get now the error page displayed?**

---

**UPDATE**

I think, it's a terrible logical mistake -- I'm trying to process some framework stuff *after* a `set_exception_handler(...)` call. Do I see it correctly? If so, it cannot work this way. **How to solve this dilemma / What is a workaround?**

Comment: Hi @automatix, Did you solve your problem ? I'm interested to know the solution. Cheers